# How to change the color of PlaceHolder in dijit/form/TextBox?

Tags: html, dojo

Im trying to assign the value to a placeHolder in dijit/form/textbox. I have used it in declarative Way...

```
<input id="searchbox" name="searchbox" value=""
                data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                style="width: 9em; height: 1.4em;font-size:14px" 
                onKeyPress="sboxOnClick">

document.getElementById("searchbox").placeholder="<font color='grey' style='font-weight:bold'>search</font>";
```

But I'm getting the value as, `<font color='grey' style='font-weight:bold'>search</font>`

Can anyone give me some suggestions/pointer on how to change the color of the placeHolder in dijit/form/TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #909;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color:    #909;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text Here" />
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLrrvLv7/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you can change the .dijitPlaceHolder in the css themes.

In my case, as I am not allowed to change the css themes, a dirty workaround is implemented

```
    dojo.query('.dijitPlaceHolder').forEach(
        function(inputElem){
            inputElem.style.fontSize = "11px";
            inputElem.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
        }
    );
```